# Python: Get word count frequency from a string?

Tags: python-3.x, count, frequency, cpu-word

Colorado!

How do I get word count frequency from a string in Python?

Steps applied --
(1) Ran getText() function to extract text from a Word document.Docx
(2) Output is 500 words as a string

```
getText() function code
def getText(filename):
doc = docx.Document(filename)
fullText = []
for para in doc.paragraphs:
    fullText.append(para.text)
return '\n'.join(fullText)
```

SAMPLE DATA                                                         BUSINESS SKILLS
Analytics: Data Analysis, Databases, Dashboards, Reports, Quantitative Math, Visualizations
Compensation: Commissions, Consulting, Data Integrations, Salary Analysis, Sales Commissions Applications
Industries: Engineering, Financial Services, Healthcare, Insurance, Real Estate, and Technology

TECHNICAL SKILLS
Software: ADP, HR Cube, Channel Management, Jama Requirements Management PayScale, PeopleSoft, Salary CompAnalyst, Salesforce, SAP
Business Intelligence: Power Business Intelligence (Power BI), Power Query, Tableau
Programming:  Python, SQL, VBA, XML
Databases: Access, MySQL, Oracle, Toad
Tools: Apple, Google, Microsoft Office, Lucidchart, Slack, Smartsheet, SFTP, and Visio

WORK EXPERIENCE
Developed salary database, data mappings, data mining, design analytics, reports, and dashboards.
Optimized database algorithms for searching jobs and market salaries based on proprietary criteria.
Communicated sales incentives plans annual changes, new enrollments, promotions, and transfers.
Performed salary planning for base and variable pay, salary market pricing, salary consulting, and total rewards statements.
Reconciled financial data for analysis using Excel Vlookups, Pivot Tables, Power Pivot, and Visual Basic.
Normalized HRIS databases to improve data warehousing using Access, HR Cube, and SQL.
Extracted data for compensation trends, forecasting, and compliance periodic reporting.

Thanks a tons for your help & sharing knowledge.
-myrna

Comment: Can you post sample data ?

Comment: @bigbounty, Sample data posted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of good tutorials out there that cover this. I like [this one](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/string/python-data-type-string-exercise-12.php) as it provides some visuals that can help explain what's going on.

The code from said tutorial (posted here for convenience):

```
def word_count(str):
    counts = dict()
    words = str.split()

    for word in words:
        if word in counts:
            counts[word] += 1
        else:
            counts[word] = 1

    return counts

print( word_count('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'))
```